# JAVA storing data into outputBuffer array and when it is full write it into file

Tags: java, arrays, io

before starting I would like to say that I've just a couple hours experience with java.Therefore if its a bit easy question sorry about it.

Now, I have a byte array and I stores bytes into it.When it reaches maximum capacity, I want to write it into binary file and continue to my loop. To do that I've implemented the following piece of code.

```
// I have an byte array my_array which has already been full 
OutputStream output=null;
output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFName)); //I'm not sure this
byte [] outputBuffer=new byte[PageSize];

int index=0; // shows the last used index in outputBuffer
for(int i=0;i<13;i++){
     // if my_array[i] holds condition{
           // if index>=PageSize{
                  // write the content of outputBuffer into outputFname
                  index=0;
           }
           // else{
                  outputBuffer[index+1]=my_array[i];
              }
      }
}
```

Now I dont know how to write it into file. Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just construct your `OutputStream` like this -

```
output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFName), PageSize);
```

and write to it normally. You can let the [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) do exactly what you asked for. The second argument to the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#BufferedOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream,%20int%29) is the buffer size.

Comment: in my real problem I'll put more than one byte into outputbuffer array if it has enough space and than I'll write it into file. In your solution I couldnt see where should I use outputbuffer array ?

Comment: @TheGost The `BufferedOutputStream` contains it... you just write. When you're done, you should call `flush()`.

Comment: when I write it, should I also use outputbuffer array ?

Comment: also sometimes outputBuffer will not be full, I mean it will contains less then PageSize, does it cause any problem ?

Comment: @TheGost Your buffer array is not needed; the `BufferedOutputStream` contains its' own. `flush()` will empty the buffer.

Comment: @Elliot-Frisch, thanks for reply. Since the second argumant of output is PageSize,I think it always write number of PageSize bytes into file right ? And if it is yes, I dont want to do it in this way as I said before ?

Comment: That's the constructor that indicates the buffer size. I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @Elliot-Frish Let me explain it more clearly. I need to a buffer with size PageSize.  I want to store an m bytes into this buffer if and only if all m bytes can fit into this buffer.If not, I need to write the content of buffer into file, clear content and store it into buffer. Is ıt clear now ?

Comment: @Elliot-Frisch this pageSize may not be the multiple of m btw

Comment: @TheGost Immaterial. You should set the buffer size to `m`, and just write to the `OutputStream`; when you're done call `flush()`.

Comment: Altough you're right,since it is an assignment I couldnt change the size of buffer.

Comment: do you have any advice now ?

Comment: I still don't understand your question. The BufferedOutputStream behaves exactly like you want.

Comment: could we continue on chat ?

Comment: @TheGost You don't have enough reputation.

Comment: than okey, Thanks for all you done, I'll try to solve it